# How to get a property value from a system containing multi-layers, each of which might contain the value

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, configuration

In many system applications, there are hundreds of property values, i.e. key-value pairs on different levels. For instance:

- Level 1 - user

  - Level 2 - role

    - Level 3 - profile

      - Level 4 - system

When a system user wants to get the value of a property, he can go to the user level in the first place, if there is not that value on the user level, he will go to the second level, i.e., based on his role for instance manager, system admin etc., if there is still no corresponding value on the role level, he will go to the profile level to get the value etc. In one word, the user searches the property values from the lowest level up to the top level

About the traits of the property values, they can be either static or dynamic values, which are subject to change.

There might be various implementations. My **question** is: **is there any existing solution from the aspects of data structures and algorithms?**

- **Case 1: data is static, which does not change**
- **Case 2: data is subject to sporadic changes**

For instance, the same property values among all the levels can be stored either separately or as a whole data structure in a **document database**, but which way is better? what are the pros and cons?

Comment: if you only need retrieval of a property, having a structure with the value for each property by preprocessing the levels is optimal. Depends too much on usage/context

Comment: It might help if you could provide some more context. For example, are you talking about a relatively small number of name=value pairs at each level, and a relatively small number of users/roles/profiles/systems to choose from? Or might there be millions/billions of them? Also, is the data static, so you can parse it once into data structures and then access the data structures directly? Or will the data be subject to sporadic updates?

Comment: @CiaranMcHale There might millions of such key-value pairs, and I would assume two conditions like you mentioned: if the data is static what solution would be better, if the data is subject to sporadic updates what solution would be better :)